# Wrapping all elements within an element until a particular tag occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to wrap all child elements of an element within a new element dynamically. I looked jQuery wrap() function but it falls short of expectation as it takes an element and wrap it around with some new element while *I want to group all child elements in some new element.*

```
/*Sample code*/
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                /* All <li> children before <UL> tag, need to be wrapped dynamically within a <span> */
                <span class="doSomting"></span>
                <a href="#">Click Me</a>

                <ul></ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

```
    /*Expected <li> element*/
    <li>
        <span>
            <span class="doSomting"></span>
            <a href="#">Click Me</a>
        </span>  
        <ul></ul>
    </li>
```

**Update**
I want to group all elements until `<UL>` tag occurs inside an `<li>`. I have updated the code snippets accordingly. Apologies for not being clear.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll)

```
$('li').contents().wrapAll('<span />')
```

Note: If you have multiple `li` elements, then you have to iterate over each `li` like

```
$('li').each(function(){
    $(this).contents().wrapAll('<span />')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/34f5u17n/)

---

Update

```
$('div > ul > li').each(function () {
    $(this).children(':not(ul)').wrapAll('<span />')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/34f5u17n/3/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response however I intended to ask little different  - I have updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: so all elements except the `ul`?

Comment: Ok, I have modified your code like **$('li').each(function () {
    $(this).contents().not('ul').wrapAll('<span />')
})** and it seems to be working

Comment: Thanks Arun, your solutions has helped me. Could you please update your answer; I shall accept it?